# KDL for a 21 dof robot

Tags: ros, kdl, robot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I work with the kdl, but i dont know how to determine the angle Limits.
Someone an idea?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173744/kdl-for-a-21-dof-robot/) by [Dante](https://answers.ros.org/users/12521/dante/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your question has very limited information on what you actually want to achieve (calculate forward kinematics, inverse kinematics, inverse dynamics, wrenches, twists etc.?). I´d recommend looking at (and possible using) [MoveIt!](http://moveit.ros.org/). It provides advanced capabilities or motion planning, but also basic kinematics functionality described [here](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Capabilities#Kinematics). If you´re more interested in the low level control side of things, this [cartesian controller](https://github.com/johmau85/hector_tedusar_workshop/blob/box_detection_and_shoring/cartesian_controller/src/cartesian_controller.cpp#L71) implementation for ros_control demonstrates how you can read a URDF file and initialize KDL objects from it.

As you might have noted, the recommended first step is to generate a [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) model or your robot, as this makes use of KDL (and many other tools in the ROS ecosystem) much easier.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dante](https://answers.ros.org/users/12521/dante/) on 2014-06-20**:
hi thanks for you answer. I find that https://github.com/kouretes/NAOKinematics. I want to calculate the center of mass from the robot.

int main(){
NAOKinematics nkin;

```
nkin2.calculateCoMChain((Frames)HEAD, (Frames)(FR_BASE_T+CHAIN_HEAD), HEAD_SIZE, m);
sumc=nkin2;
summass=m;

return 0;
```

}

Something is wrong. Someone an idea?